# (Image processing iOS) crop object from image

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, gpuimage

I currently working on an iOS project in which I am trying to crop an object out of an image. An example of what I am looking for is here https://clippingmagic.com. I not looking for code **I am just looking for what image processing techniques would I have to use to achieve this**. I am currently using OpenCV framework for iOS to perform things like canny edge detection etc...

[image: This an example what I would like to do.]